# hibernate relationship can't found foreign key on annotation way

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I'm  new to hibernate try lean hibernate relationship and have tow table,
relationship is one to many

```
  create table student(
    id bigint primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(20),
    student_class_id bigint foreign key references student_class(id)
  )

  create table student_class(
    id bigint primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(20)
  )
```

spring sessionFactory bean have configured packageToScan entity

this is entity class:

```
@Table(name = "students")
@Entity
public class Student {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer name;
    private StudentClass studentClass;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public Integer getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(Integer name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_class_id")
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    public StudentClass getStudentClass() {
        return studentClass;
    }
    // setter getter
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "student_class")
public class StudentClass {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "studentClass", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }
    /setter getter
}
```

sql is: `select sc.name from StudentClass sc left join Student s on sc.id = s.student_class_id`

and junit test fount error

```
[DEBUG] 2018-05-26 11:59:39.993 [main] HqlSqlBaseWalker - select << begin [level=1, statement=select]
[DEBUG] 2018-05-26 11:59:40.005 [main] FromElement - FromClause{level=1} : com.f.pojo.StudentClass (sc) -> studentcla0_
[DEBUG] 2018-05-26 11:59:40.009 [main] HqlSqlWalker - Creating entity-join FromElement [s -> com.f.pojo.Student]
[DEBUG] 2018-05-26 11:59:40.010 [main] FromElement - FromClause{level=1} : com.f.pojo.Student (s) -> student1_
[DEBUG] 2018-05-26 11:59:40.012 [main] FromReferenceNode - Resolved : sc -> studentcla0_.id
[DEBUG] 2018-05-26 11:59:40.013 [main] DotNode - getDataType() : id -> org.hibernate.type.IntegerType@26a2f7f9
[DEBUG] 2018-05-26 11:59:40.013 [main] FromReferenceNode - Resolved : sc.id -> studentcla0_.id
[DEBUG] 2018-05-26 11:59:40.013 [main] FromReferenceNode - Resolved : s -> student1_.id
[ERROR] 2018-05-26 11:59:40.016 [main] ErrorTracker -  could not resolve property: student_class_id of: com.f.pojo.Student
[ERROR] 2018-05-26 11:59:40.016 [main] ErrorTracker -  could not resolve property: student_class_id of: com.f.pojo.Studentcker -  could not resolve property: student_class_id of: com.f.pojo.Student
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: could not resolve property: student_class_id of: com.f.pojo.Student [select sc.name from com.f.pojo.StudentClass sc left join com.f.pojo.Student s on sc.id = s.student_class_id]
```

I'm two entity relationship seem be right, student entity using `studentClass` property references `studentClass` entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL:

```
create table student(
```

Your class:

```
@Table(name = "students")
```

These names need to match. Even a single character (s) makes a big difference.

Another problem in your SQL:

```
name varchar(20),
```

Your class:

```
private Integer name;
```

The type also needs to match. I believe you meant to use String in your class instead of Integer.